# Twillio Studio Send and receive text message

Tags: twilio, twilio-studio

i am new to twillio studio and can send texts one way, but want to be able to do the following.

1. Recieve a text from a twillio number to my cell
2. Reply to the text from my cell back to the twilio number path

I can find info and get a project working for step 1 , but am having a issue wil info on step 2.

Any suggestions.

Thanks
Tom

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you are using the Twilio Studio REST API Trigger of your Studio Flow, can you confirm?

[Trigger a Twilio Studio Flow Execution via the REST API](https://support.twilio.com/hc/en-us/articles/360007778153-Trigger-a-Twilio-Studio-Flow-Execution-via-the-REST-API)

If that is the case, just have the Trigger Widget REST API path follow into a [Send and Wait for Reply Widget](https://www.twilio.com/docs/studio/widget-library/send-wait-reply). This is all you need to do to satisfy #1 and #2 above.

Comment: I am using incoming message in the trigger, but it sounds like I should be using Rest Api is that correct?

Comment: The Studio REST API Trigger is ideal for initially kicking off a process (Twilio > Outbound). Whereas the Voice and Message paths of the Studio Trigger Widget are ideal when someone is calling or sending an inbound SMS to your Twilio number (Inbound > Twilio). In you example, you want to initiate the conversation without any first action from the other side, correct?

Comment: So I want to respond to incoming text messages from the twilio number. The text comes in through twilio number, the message comes to my cell number and i respond back through to the incoming text.Is this what you mean? Thanks

Comment: Ah ok, Studio is designed for Human-to-Bot interactions primarily. You can follow this blog to allow two way SMS using Twilio Functions to handle the routing logic. SMS Forwarding and Responding Using Twilio and JavaScript - https://www.twilio.com/blog/sms-forwarding-and-responding-using-twilio-and-javascript

Comment: I added the information from the blog , but am getting the following errors and I am not sure why.  Error - 11200 and Error - 82002.

Comment: I set-up the same blog, so I know the code works. Can you verify you typed in the function code exactly? If you bring the Function up via the Twilio Console when testing it out, you may see an error in the lower console portion, which could provide a clue.